# content between app-root not rendered in angular?

Tags: angular

Environment: Angular version: 8, ionic 4

Issue: the content in between the root component tags is supposed to be rendered before angular app is 
initialized.

`<app-root>Loading...</app-root>`

the `loading` text is shown when app is reloaded when serving using `ng serve`

But doesn't show up when using the command `ng serve --prod`.

Please help